# Can't import files in the same directory (and subdirectories) - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: directory, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run some GitHub code and I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deep_knn'` when I run `from deep_knn import Deep_KNN`. Same thing happens when I try `import utils.tensorflow_utils as tf_utils`. Here is a picture of the folders:[image]

I'm using Python 3.8.10 and I'm in the DeepNNK_polytope_interpolation directory. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out- I ran `!cd '/content/DeepNNK_polytope_interpolation/'` but it should've been `!cd DeepNNK_polytope_interpolation`.